# detect us military email address

Tags: regex, email

Does anybody know which domains to search for (other than ".mil") to look for military addresses posting to a web form?

Clarification: we're offering a discount to our customers, and we really only have time to cough up an email address regex which can fit into our existing system.

This is on LAMP.

Comment: *black helicopters dispatched*

Comment: Any examples of domains you're talking about that don't end in .mil?

Comment: While I can think of several reasons why this is a bad question (not really programming relatd, doesn't really give an explanation of the platform being used, etc.) I get annoyed at random down-voters giving no explanation. Why was this downvoted?

Comment: @skaffman -- as i was posting, i thought similarly
@Will -- .edu, .com, .foo
@San Jacinto -- i saved myself and you time by not boring you with implementation details.  it is a perfectly apt programming question!

Answer (score 2):

It would more than likely depend on the command that the person is associated with. .mil for pure military email addresses, .gov for sometype of goverment entitiy that they're associated with, or even .edu as someone else mentioned for educational instutions. It's also quite possible that people could have .com, .org or even .net addresses.

Unless you know for sure that a person will be posting to your webform with a military address, I think you might find it somewhat difficult to determine the authenticity of an indivdual just through an email address' domain.

Good luck in your project.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, .mil is the only on that is officially supported by the US Government, but not 100% sure.

Depending on what you want, you would have to keep an eye out for sites such as this as well - http://www.usmilitary.com/

Answer (score 0):

.mil seems to be the only official military email extension, however I believe they also use .edu for their Academy email addresses.

Answer (score -2):

*Hi -- does anybody know which domains to search for (other than ".mil") to look for military addresses posting to a web form?*

I don't understand. What you're basically asking here, is what are us military domains ? Right ?

If I understood wrongly, and you're searching for ways of parsing or matching email adresses, then several regex methods for that have already been posted on SO, so I guess finding them shouldn't prove too difficult.

Comment: i searched for "regex military email" on SO and came up with no fast answers

Comment: In the last paragraph, I was talking about matching emails in general. With that in mind, upon searching "regex email" several answers show.